# How to share a self-signed clickonce certificate with different clients for development

Tags: certificate, clickonce, sharing, self-signed

I am developing a clickonce C sharp project in Visual Studio.
On my main computer, I have generated a self-signed certificate for the clickonce manifest.
This works fine, I can compile, deploy and run.
I also sync this solution to my github account, and regularly pull updates down to a backup computer.
The backup computer is not able to simply compile this solution, as it gives errors in regards to self-signed keys.
I could generate a new one on the backup computer, but then when I deploy to same testbed, it causes issues because the certificate is from a different location.
I want to quickly be able to deploy from the backup computer in the event that there is an issue with the main.
How can I share the main computer's generated certificate with my backup environment without issue?

My apologies if this is straightforward or I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Run `certmgr.msc` (user) or `certlm.msc` (computer) and look in `My Certificates` for the certificate. Right click it an check if you can export it with the private key resulting in am PFX file (PKCS#12).

If this is not possible [generate a new one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps) with the `-ExportPolicy Exportable` option.